# UCanAccess - Mirror Folder files are not being recreated when Access database is changed by another program

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

Mirror Folder files are not being recreated when Access database is changed by another program.

The below is my connection string:

```
jdbc:ucanaccess://E:\db\CostData.accdb;memory=false;keepMirror=C:\Users\Nader Costantine\h2db\accessdbmirror\CostData1475734597482\CostData
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better explain your issue. Are you saying that `keepMirror` is preventing UCanAccess from seeing external changes to the database? If so, then under what conditions does this occur?

Answer (score -1):

Solved the connection should be closed in order to re